# What Force power(s) did Yoda use to defend against Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, revenge-of-the-sith

In the movie, Yoda can be seen using the Force to absorb incoming Force Lightning and - I'm unsure if it's the same power - fire the absorbed energy back at Palpatine or something to the same effect.

What is/are these Force power(s), if there is a name for it?

Is the **canon** version capable of defending against a lightsaber strike, similar to what the Legendary Jedi Master Satele Shan did in one of the SWTOR trailers? Is it restricted to only stabs?

Comment: Based on the fact that Dooku switches to his lightsaber when his lightning attacks fail would strongly imply that you can't block a stab.

Comment: Yup. It's not named in the main canon but there's a whole mess of [crap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tutaminis) on wookieepedia about force-lighting absorption

Comment: @Valorum - Or that it’s harder, more likely. We’ve seen people block blaster bolts and Force Lightning…it’s only a matter of time for lightsabers. *Star Wars* VIII, perhaps?